# C# to Python messaging

Tags: python, c#, zeromq

I want to send and receive very simple data (doesn't matter what form) from/to C# to/from a python program on a raspberry pi using ZeroMQ. For my server side I am using the following C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using NetMQ;
using NetMQ.Sockets;

namespace NetMQServer
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var server = new ResponseSocket())
            {
                server.Bind("tcp://*:5555");
                while (true)
                {
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    var message = server.ReceiveFrameString();
                    Console.WriteLine("Received {0}", message);
                    // processing the request
                    Console.WriteLine("Sending World");
                    server.SendFrame("World");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and on the client side (python) I am using the following code:

```
import zmq

context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.REQ)
socket.connect("tcp://192.168.1.14:5555")

for i in range(0, 10):
    print("Sending Hello")
    socket.send_string("Hello")
    msg = socket.recv_string()
    print("recieved ", msg)
    print("")
```

both programs run but it does not print anything in the console as if they are not connected. I have tried it with both client and server in the same language with the exact same codes above and it works.

Comment: Communication is via ZeroMQ; why do the languages matter at all? You need to clarify your question with details of *what* doesn't work, isolate it to client or server, and post a reproducible example, in the language you're having trouble with. Please improve your question.

Comment: @CoolBots That's what I am asking. because the same code works for when both sides are either python or C#. but in the above case, the programs run without errors but nothing gets printed to the screen.

Comment: Language doesn't matter; in fact, it'd be *impossible* for one side to figure out what language the other side is written in. There's likely a difference in your implementation between the working example and the failing one. You need to figure out what the issue is. "Nothing is printing..." is not a technical description - use logging, or even breakpoints, to determine if the message is being sent, but not received, or not sent at all, etc. But it's not about language used on client/server.

Comment: @CoolBots - with all due respect, I can confirm, that languages do matter ( not per se, but due to their ZeroMQ bindings not always follow the native ZeroMQ API well enough, so that the results are dependent this way on what language / wrapper / binding was used to assemble / disassemble the ZMTP-defined ZeroMQ message ... ) In this sense I have to support the O/P's wording of what tries to communicate with what.

Comment: @user3666197 I agree with this point; certainly bindings implementations can cause issues.

Answer (score 0):

I run your code on a local machine and cannot reproduce your issue - an interaction between client and server works fine.

Just one remark, this code:

```
Console.ReadKey();
```

should be removed from the server-side.

---

I would recommend:

- make sure that all works on a local machine
- check that port *5555* is available (not blocked by a firewall, etc) from the client-side. To test it can be used *telnet* utility:

```sh
telnet 192.168.1.14 5555
```

Comment: Thanks Vladimir. So After I restarted my computer running the server code, it works. I have been trying to reproduce the erroneous behaviour and have been unsuccessful so far. So not sure what I did wrong. Could you elaborate why I shouldn't use Console.ReadKey() on server side?

Comment: And also, the problem I am almost sure was not because the port was busy or the firewall, If it happens again I will try to debug it to see what is wrong and post the result here

Comment: Service should not interact with any user through Console it is no a client app (consider using message queue to pass some commands, etc). So call of *Console.ReadKey();* looks suspicious.